# HTAccess Rewrite Issues

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am writing a website which is dynamically populated through an Oracle database.

I have completed the desktop site and am now required to create a mobile site. Due to how different the sites are planned to look, I have opted to create 2 different "template" like websites for the mobile and desktop sites.

However, for my desktop site, everything is built off the index.php file in order to allow it to be completely dynamic. Pages are therefore look like `www.domain.com/index.php/page` in the url.

For the desktop site, this works. I am using a generic index.php removal rewrite rule in order to then make the url `www.domain.com/page` however still display the same page as the previous URL.

My issue, is that now I have a `www.domain.com/mobile/index.php`. Which has been created and for the most part has been working, however when trying to add addition dynamic pages to the mobile site. `www.domain.com/mobile/index.php/about` for example just redirects to `www.domain.com/mobile/` and it doesn't even include the `about` part of the URL.

After much debugging, I have discovered it is definitely the `.htaccess` that is causing the issue.

If you have any insight into my issue, please help me out.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT 1**

Rewrite Rules are as follows

```
# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

# Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Please add the rewrite rules to your question.

Comment: Do you have .htaccess inside `/mobile/` also?

Comment: I don't but should I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `/mobile/.htaccess` file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mobile/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*))?$ $1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

This will override all the rules present in parent .htaccess for `/mobile/` URI path.

---

**Simplified version to make it work in root .htaccess:**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(mobile)/(.*)$ $1/index.php/$2 [L,NC]

# Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I didn't wan't to have more than one .htaccess for the site, however looking at your answer, logically it would work, and therefore I will accept this answer however for those who see this question and like me wanted to do it all in one file, I have posted my solution too.

Comment: Thanks for accepting. I have also posted a simplified version of root .htaccess from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the debugging you mentioned, there is a rule in your .htaccess which is rewriting `www.domain.com/mobile/index.php/about` to `www.domain.com/mobile/`. So, if you find which rule this is, you can add one *above* it that will catch requested URLs for your mobile pages and then not allow the problematic following rule to run. Something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^mobile/index.php/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)$ ^mobile/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

The `L` ensures that if the user's request matches this rule, no further rules (including the one causing the issue) will be executed.

Comment: Do you have any clue which of the 2 Rules it is? or should I just put that above both rules?

Comment: Also, the rule you've posted looks like its not going to replace the index.php with nothing. Basically what I want to end up with is `mobile/home` which equates to `mobile/index.php/home` which should be possible

Comment: I think what is happening is `RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]` is matching strings that start with `index.php` as well as `mobile/index.php` - use the caret (`^`) operator and create separate rules for strings that start with `index.php` and `mobile/index.php`.

Comment: Oh, okay. Try:

`RewriteRule ^mobile/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)$ ^mobile/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]`.

This will grab strings that start with `mobile/whatever`, and rewrite them to `mobile/index.php/whatever`

Comment: Is it possible to do this with a RewriteCond instead of a rule?

Comment: `RewriteCond`s apply only to the first `RewriteRule` following them. You are trying to define how the `.htaccess` is rewriting a URL requested by the user, so you will ultimately need a rule for that somewhere (upstream of the current `RewriteRule`, otherwise that will catch the request first).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers you've both given, however neither of them worked, I've now solved the issue, it was to do with the final RewriteRule at the end

```
# Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

I needed to change it to

```
# Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/mobile/.* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /mobile/.* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mobile/index.php/$1 [L]
```

So that it would work with both mobile and desktop sites.